# cocoa NSFileManager wrong file size

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I'm using NSFileManager to get the size of some files in our application.

Each file is examined by a separate thread and the result for all the files is the same wrong value. The following code is ran for each file in a separate thread:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager= [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSUInteger completedFileSize = [[[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:fileName error:&error] objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedLongValue];
NSLog(@"Part %lu: %@ => size:%lu actual size:%lu", myPart.SequenceNumber, fileName, completedFileSize, myPart.Size);
```

The output is:

> Part 1: /Users/David/TEMP/245E0BF53ECA/part1 => size:36864 actual size:37187
>
> Part 5: /Users/David/TEMP/245E0BF53ECA/part5 => size:36864 actual size:37187
>
> Part 2: /Users/David/TEMP/245E0BF53ECA/part2 => size:36864 actual size:37187
>
> Part 4: /Users/David/TEMP/245E0BF53ECA/part4 => size:36864 actual size:37187
>
> Part 3: /Users/David/TEMP/245E0BF53ECA/part3 => size:36864 actual size:37187
>
> Part 6: /Users/David/TEMP/245E0BF53ECA/part6 => size:36864 actual size:37187
>
> Part 7: /Users/David/TEMP/245E0BF53ECA/part7 => size:36864 actual size:37186
>
> Part 0: /Users/David/TEMP/245E0BF53ECA/part0 => size:36864 actual size:37189

Also output of **ls -l** command on terminal is identical to the correct file sizes previously saved in **myPart.Size**

> -rw-r--r--  1 David  staff  37189 Nov 25 11:25 part0
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 David  staff  37187 Nov 25 11:25 part1
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 David  staff  37187 Nov 25 11:25 part2
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 David  staff  37187 Nov 25 11:25 part3
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 David  staff  37187 Nov 25 11:25 part4
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 David  staff  37187 Nov 25 11:25 part5
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 David  staff  37187 Nov 25 11:25 part6
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 David  staff  37186 Nov 25 11:25 part7

I'm using OS X 10.8 and Xcode 4.5.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't say how `myPart.Size` is calculated.

Comment: Are you sure that the fileName variable is set correctly and you don't need something like [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%lu", fileName, myPart.SequenceNumber]?

Comment: Yes the fileName is correct because the log indicates the fact.

Comment: This: NSLog(@"Part %lu: %@ => size:%lu actual size:%lu", myPart.SequenceNumber, fileName, completedFileSize, myPart.Size); can't produce the output you listed.

Comment: Thanks. I had a mistake copying the output. I fixed it but it really doesn't help much.

Comment: Actually a bigger file is broken into parts and myPart.Size is the size of each part which is correct as the ls command shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the actual problem!

The file is not closed before the:

```
[[[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:fileName error:&error] objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedLongValue];
```

so I closed the file handler associated with **fileName** variable for **path** and the problem is solved.

```
fclose(myFile); //this is the handler for fileName
//now the value returned from the below line is correct.
[[[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:fileName error:&error] objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedLongValue];
```

Thanks from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the defaultManager and fileSize to calculate the file size.

```
unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:someFilePath error:nil] fileSize];
```

Comment: [NSFileManager defaultManager] is not thread safe and [[NSFileManager alloc] init] should be used instead. I also tried fileSize and the result is the same.

Comment: @DavidJames That's not accurate. From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/): "The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely. However, if you use a delegate to receive notifications about the status of move, copy, remove, and link operations, you should create a unique instance of the file manager object, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager to initiate your operations."